# Custom data annotation with RIa Services

Tags: c#, reflection, data-annotations, wcf-ria-services

I have a Silverlight application and I'm using Entity Framework and Ria Services.

I need to create a custom attribute that I will use to recognize some properties.

Ex. :

```
public class Person
{
    [IsSpecialProperty]
    public string PersonProperty { get; set; }
}

public class IsSpecialPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

I named the class file "IsSpecialPropertyAttribute.shared.cs" to access it from the client.

And from the client side, I use the method :

```
var attributes = (IsSpecialPropertyAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(memberInfo, typeof(IsSpecialPropertyAttribute));
```

This method is working for system attributes but not with my custom attribute...

Any idea why ?

This method give me all the other attributes, but not the custom I created...

```
var test = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(memberInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try two other approaches:

```
var attributes = memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsSpecialPropertyAttribute), true);
```

or:

```
var attribute = person.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsSpecialPropertyAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as IsSpecialPropertyAttribute;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. "Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(memberInfo);" get the list of all other attributes, but not the one I created...